# Why is it not possible to reference PresentationCore.dll without <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, .net-8.0

I try to include a WPF-Window into a ConsoleApp.
For this, I have referenced

- PresentationCore.dll
- PresentationFramework.dll
- WindowsBase.dll

But when I try to execute the App, I get the Exception

> System.BadImageFormatException   HResult=0x80131058   Message=Could
> not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=8.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Reference
> assemblies cannot be loaded for execution. (0x80131058)
> Source=   StackTrace:
>
> Inner Exception 1: BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference
> assembly for execution.

I know that I can include `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>` but I want to understand, why this is necessary and it is not enough to reference the WPF-Framework (like it was in .NET 4.8).

Thanks for your explenation.

Comment: You probably added a reference to PresentationFramework.dll from the packs/Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref folder (don't make us guess).  MSBuild dutifully copied it, not knowing that it should avoid doing so.  Pick it from shared/Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App folder and it won't complain.  Or use UseWPF, you are.

Comment: I'm not sure what the "useWPF" flag does specifically. But WPF is only available on widows, not linux or Mac, so I would expect the purpose is simplify the configuration and reduce the risk of incompatible configurations. .Net 4.8 only exists for windows, so such incompatibilities is not a concern.

Comment: @HansPassant You are right - I have used the dll's from the wrong place. When I change to shared, I get the exception: System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'PresentationNative_cor3.dll' or one of its dependencies: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden. (0x8007007E)'
And when I try to ad PresentationNative_cor3.dll it will say that this is not possible.

Comment: @JonasH _"I'm not sure what the "useWPF" flag does specifically"_ it enables .NET Desktop SDK - see [MSBuild reference for .NET Desktop SDK projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props-desktop#enable-net-desktop-sdk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSBuild reference for .NET Desktop SDK projects: Enable .NET Desktop SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props-desktop#enable-net-desktop-sdk) section:

> To use WinForms or WPF, configure your project file. .NET 5 and later versions:
>
> - Target the .NET SDK `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`.
> - Set `TargetFramework` to a Windows-specific target framework moniker, such as `net6.0-windows`.
> - **Add a UI framework property (or both, if necessary):**
>
>   - Set `UseWPF` to `true` to import and use WPF.
>   - Set `UseWindowsForms` to `true` to import and use WinForms.
> - (Optional) Set `OutputType` to `WinExe`. This produces an app as opposed to a library. To produce a library, omit this property.

So basically it is how project should be set up to use corresponding components, just add `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>` without adding corresponding dlls.

And [`UseWPF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props-desktop#usewpf) section:

> The `UseWPF` property controls whether or not to include references to WPF libraries. This also alters the MSBuild pipeline to correctly process a WPF project and related files. The default value is `false`. Set the `UseWPF` property to `true` to enable WPF support. You can only target the Windows platform when this property is enabled.
> When this property is set to `true`, .NET 5+ projects will automatically import the .NET Desktop SDK.

Comment: The question says "I know that I can include <UseWPF>true</UseWPF> but I want to understand, why this is necessary."  This answer says "It is necessary because microsoft says so."